# P-value for difference between two groups of curves

Tags: p-value

I have two groups of curves that are clearly different. How I can calculate p-value?

Green and blue curves is the average of about 10 curves from each group. The filled area is standard deviation. And the black curve at the bottom is the difference between average curves.

[image]

Comment: Just stating that the curves are different would seem not to be of great interest because the differences are likely not identical across all values of the horizontal variable.  Would you not want to know where the differences occur and an estimate of the size of the differences?  If so, a single *P*-value (even if we were told how the 20 curves came into existence) would not be informative.  Is an unenlightened journal editor insisting that you have a *P*-value?

Comment: No it is not journal editor. It is just my curiosity. I would like to know if there are some criteria that allows to say that two groups of curves are statistically different and some test for statistical significance.

Comment: You haven't yet described as to how the two groups of curves came into existence.  Are these all estimated from a single dataset with maybe some common parameters that were estimated?  Related datasets?  Is the grouping known beforehand or did you group the curves after fitting?

Answer (score 0):

If the curves represented something like a distribution, you could use Komogorov-
Smirnoff test [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), but it doesn't look like they are distributions.

Depending on what it is about the curves you're trying to capture, you may consider simply reducing it to a simpler description of the curve y(x); say max(y), or min(y), or avg(y) over the interval x. (You may even consider a mesure like the diff(y_green - y_blue) over samples in x.) Then you would effectively have 2 samples, and could proceed with standard techniques from there.

Comment: The two curves are samples, not distributions.

Comment: That is what I did, but I just would like to know if there are some other tests that could be applied directly to the curves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two-samples Kolmogorov–Smirnov test to test whether the two samples come from the same distribution. In your example, I am sure you will be able to reject the null hypothesis.